# X11 forwarding in SSH

Tags: xorg, openssh, x11-forwarding

How to run X11 GUI applications from a remote server using SSH?

For example:

- my first desktop 192.168.1.1
- my second desktop IP 192.168.1.12

I 'm sshing from my first desktop to the second and i want to run the GUI applications from the second and redirect X11 to the first.

Comment: try ssh -l user 192.168.1.12 -X. Start app.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following command to create the ssh connection:

```
ssh -X remote_login@192.168.1.12
```

Just replace remote_login by your second desktop login

`ssh` man page:

> -X   Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host
>        basis in a configuration file.
>
> ```
>  X11 forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
>  ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
>  user's X authorization database) can access the local X11 display
>  through the forwarded connection.  An attacker may then be able
>  to perform activities such as keystroke monitoring.
>
>  For this reason, X11 forwarding is subjected to X11 SECURITY
>  extension restrictions by default.  Please refer to the ssh -Y
>  option and the ForwardX11Trusted directive in ssh_config(5) for
>  more information.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a way:

```
ssh -X user@192.168.1.12
```

Then when I login I just easily can start whatever GUI app I need. I tried Firefox and yes I can just use Firefox from the second computer. That's really nice.