# Activate remote desktop on my ubuntu server, which interface/program?

Tags: server, gui, remote-desktop

I have a server running the ubuntu 14 LTS. Right now I need to activate the remote desktop option because there is some operation that I can't do with the terminal but I need to use program interface (so I need also a remote desktop connection).

I knew only GNOME or Unity. There is any other option? I would like to install fewer packages possible and keep the system smooth.

On the second hand, how can I connect through the remote desktop? Which technology to do you suggest (SSH, VNC, NX, etc..)? My home connection isn't very fast..

Comment: gui on server adds very little if anything as you can do everything on the command line.What problem are you having and what makes you think you can not fix it without a GUI ?

Comment: For remote connections I prefer ssh + keys for security (disable password authentication). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH . If you feel you need a gui use a web based solution such as cockpit or webmin - http://cockpit-project.org/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen there are a few little programs (eg: Plex) that are configurable only trough their interface

Comment: @bodhi.zazen thanks, now I'll explore the web based gui. I didn't know them!

Comment: Plex has a web interface - https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288586-Installation

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yes I know. But with the web interface you can only use some function if you are connected from an external network. If you want the access to the configuration, explore the file on the machine and other stuff like this you must have a local access

Comment: ok, the web based interface aren't a solution in my case.. thanks anyway

Comment: for those rare situations, I would forward X applications over ssh rather then install all of or a large desktop on the server. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/436725/x11-forwarding-in-ssh or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've resolved with the solution proposed in the comment by `bodhi.zazen`. I didn't it was possible to forward the X11 applications through the ssh connection and use the graphic interface. You can find the detailed explanation here: [askubuntu.com/questions/436725/x11-forwarding-in-ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436725/x11-forwarding-in-ssh)

So the final solution was by directly launching the interested application or by installing a lightweight browser to manage the other programs (like in the case of Plex).