# How to open and edit PHP files in Ubuntu server?

Tags: command-line, server, php, sublime-text

When I'm trying to open my PHP file in gedit command through terminal it's showing this error statement.

[image]

but it's working when nano command is typed.

[image]

I want to open my php file in sublime or some other editor. How is it possible? Is there any command or any installation required?

Comment: SSH? https://askubuntu.com/questions/436725/x11-forwarding-in-ssh

Answer (score 9):

For this purpose I suggest using `sshfs`. Your desired path from your server will be mounted on your local filesystem and you will be able to work with files as they are located in your own computer.

To install:

```
sudo apt install sshfs
```

To use:

```
mkdir ~/mount-server
sshfs user@192.168.56.12:/var/www/html/dir ~/mount-server
```

Now `/var/www/html/dir` is mounted on your `~/mount-server`, and you can use whatever softwares you are using to work with these files, your own file manager, editors, etc.

to unmount it run:

```
fusermount -u ~/mount-server
```

Comment: I installed SSHFS in terminal but again I'm getting this error bro.

Comment: You shouldn't run applications on your server, use the above instruction to mount the desired directory on your local system.  then go to `~/mount-server` your files are there. use sublime on your system (not server) to open files within ~/mount-server`.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are connecting with ssh. The problem is that your server doesn't know about the display on your client machine by default, and therefore cannot open X windows. To do so you need to activate X forwarding, which will tell your server to open X windows on the X11 server running on your desktop, and how to do that.

In short you need to add `-X` to your ssh command:

```
ssh -X user@ubuntu-Teclab.example.com
```

There is [a great answer on how to best set this up on the Unix & Linux SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-to-run-graphics-applications-remotely). This could be especially useful as you seem to be switching to the root user on the server, and this typically leads to a few extra complications with xauth. But basically the `-X` option should be enough in most cases.